# getting items from a SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object

From what I can tell, a SimpleXMLElement is just an array of other SimpleXMLElements, plus some regular array values if there wasn't a tag nested in another tag.

I have a SimpleXMLElement in a variable `$data`, and `var_dump($data)` gives me this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (33) {
  ["buyer-accepts-marketing"]=>
  string(4) "true"
...
...
```

but calling `var_dump($data->buyer-accepts-marketing)` gives me an error, and `var_dump($data["buyer-accepts-marketing"])` gives me NULL. Calling `var_dump($data->shipping-address->children())` gives me an error.

going like this:

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
```

gives a whole bunch of SimpleXMLElement objects, but oddly enough, no strings or ints.

What am I missing here? I want to take specific portions of it and pass them to a function, so for example, I don't have to go

```
$data->billing-address->postal-code;

...

$data->shipping-address->postal-code;

...
```

and can just go

```
address($data->billing-address);
address($data->shipping-address);
```

etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SimpleXMLElement is *not* just an array. To access child elements, you must use object notation (`$a->b`) and to access attributes you must use array notation (`$a['b']`).

Problem is, with object notation, valid tag names can be illegal PHP code.

You need to do this:

```
$data->{'buyer-accepts-marketing'};
```

Note that this returns a SimpleXMLElement! The reason for this is that it can contain either just text, more child elements, or both. The output of `var_dump()` is very misleading for SimpleXMLElements. If you want to the text content of a single `<buyer-accepts-marketing>` tag, you have to do this:

```
(string)$data->{'buyer-accepts-marketing'};
```

Of course it is also perfectly legal to do this:

```
(int)$data->{'buyer-accepts-marketing'};
```

The reason this appears to work in some cases (such as `echo`ing a SimpleXMLElement) is that the type conversions are implicit and automatic. You can't `echo` an object, so PHP automatically converts it to a string.

I have a love/hate relationship with SimpleXML. It makes things very *easy* only after you understand how *complex* the actual API is.

Read up on the so-called "[basic](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)" examples to get a good handle on it.